# How can I tell if my domain is on an email blacklist?

Tags: email, gmail, domain, google-workspace, spam-prevention

All of a sudden, emails I send to my wife's Gmail account are getting rejected as spam:

> Message rejected. Please visit http://www.google.com/mail/help/bulk_mail.html to review our Bulk Email Senders Guidelines.

I am running Google Apps on my own personal domain.  Nothing has changed about my email configuration for over a year, so I am wondering if maybe my domain got blacklisted.  Is there a way to check if it was blacklisted and maybe resolve the issues that are causing it to appear as spam?

Comment: I corrected what I hope was a typo "my wives' Gmail account" into "my wife's Gmail account" :-)

Comment: Who's to say how people live their own lives?

Comment: I think his wives sharing the same email account is very poor security.

Comment: @splattne: Thanks yes, that was a typo.  I am better about security then that.  ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the [Email Blacklist lookup tool](http://www.blacklistmonitoring.com/lookup/email_blacklist_IP_address_lookup.php).

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for, any my domain was **Not Found**.  I guess that is good, but now I need to figure out why I am bouncing.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. Now I know for sure my domain is not blacklisted.

Answer (score 6):

One more additional piece of information related to Domain blacklist:

SBRS (SenderBase Reputation Score) - the world's largest email traffic monitoring service, with data on more than 25% of the world's email and web traffic. IronPort's SenderBase Network provides an unprecedented real-time view into security threats from around the world. With this information SenderBase can be used as a "credit reporting service" for email, providing comprehensive data that ISPs and companies can use to differentiate legitimate senders from spammers and other attackers and giving email administrators visibility into who is sending them email.

Type a domain name and check the SBRS here - http://www.senderbase.org/

Comment: Good information and a good resource.  Thanks.  I would accept both this answer and John's if I could.

Answer (score 1):

There are a multitude of reasons that email can be marked as spam. If you are lucky, you get a "bounce" email, and if you are even luckier, it will have some links to where to go next.

You seem to be in the luckier category. :-)

You should follow the links, and read through and follow any advice. Google and its servers, which I also use for a hosted domain, seem as susceptible as any to being marked as the source of spam.

Unfortunately, if your emails are being marked as spam by the filter on the receivers host or ISP, then it is the person you are emailing who would have to complain, and often there is no way to manually correct the problem.

Most hosted email accounts (like gmail, hotmail etc), will let through more mail, if the recipient has you in their contacts.

In Australia I find Telstra's Bigpond service (bigpond.com and bigpond.com.au) is often one of the most aggressive about filtering, and neither the sender nor the recipient has any knowledge of the missed email, until you discover it didn't get through.

Comment: The link GMail sent me are for cleaning up my bulk emailing.  This is just individual emails, not bulk, so it completely doesn't apply.